# New todo created but not displayed - todos app with EmberJS without ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am getting started with EmberJS, followed the [Screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QHrlFlaXdI). I am trying to do the TODOs app without ember-data. 
Following is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember.js • TodoMVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">

      <section id="todoapp">
        <header id="header">
          <h1>todos</h1>
          {{input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" value=newTitle action="createTodo"}}
        </header>

        <section id="main">
          <ul id="todo-list">
            {{#each}}
              <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
              </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>

          <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
        </section>

        <footer id="footer">
          <span id="todo-count">
            <strong>2</strong> todos left
          </span>
          <ul id="filters">
            <li>
              <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="active">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="completed">Completed</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <button id="clear-completed">
            Clear completed (1)
          </button>
        </footer>
      </section>

      <footer id="info">
        <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
      </footer>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript - all in one place.

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' });
});

Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   actions:{
      createTodo: function(){
         var title = this.get('newTitle');
         if(!title.trim()){return;}
         todos.push({
            id: todos[todos.length-1].id +1,
            title: title,
            isCompleted: false
         });
         this.set('newTitle','');
      }
   }
});

Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return todos;
    }
});

var todos=[{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Learn Ember.js',
      isCompleted: true
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      title: '...',
      isCompleted: false
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Profit!',
      isCompleted: false
}];
```

The problem is when I try to add a new todo entry, it is not shown in the UI as added, but when I type `todos` on the console.

I see the new entry had been added. Why is it that the model is changed but nothing is shown in the UI ?

I also notice that the new entry in the todos array does not have methods like `getTitle`, `setTitle`, `get isCompleted`, `set isCompleted` that other objects have - which makes me think I am definitely not missing something here.

It seems like I need to get hold of model for TodosRoute and add to it, if that is what I need to do.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `todos.pushObject()` instead of simple `array.push()`.

Short explanation: "Push the object onto the end of the array. Works just like push() but it is KVO-compliant." http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject

Somewhat longer explanation: While Ember extends JS objects like array by default to make them better citizen in Emberland, it doesn't override existing methods like `push()`. This is why you need to use a separate method (`pushObject`) - it's Ember's solution to make data binding work on JS objects like an array.

Almost the same goes for plain JS objects: Ember has `Ember.Object`, which [has some methods of it's own](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get), which are not needed when all you need is a classic JS object. That doesn't mean you must use `Ember.Object` every time, in this case Ember is smart enough to set up data binding for you, based on the properties you access from your Handlebars template.